# Spring boot data hibernate different datasources

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot, spring-4

I am playing with `spring-boot` and `spring-boot-data-jpa`. I need that `@Entity class A {...}` uses `hsqlDatasource` and `@Entity class B {...}` use `mssqlDatasource`. How can I achieve that?

I would like to do something like this:

```
@Repository
@UseDatasource("hsql")
interface A extends CrudRepository....
```

Comment: In Spring Boot there is no such annotation, so you would need to configure each data source yourself and turn off the datasource autoconfiguration. After you do that, I don't know how easy it would be to get Spring Data JPA to work with multiple datasources

Comment: So you mean Spring data doesn't support such use case? I can do this "all by myself" but I don't think that using multiple datasources within app is something rare. It would be really great if spring-data support that.

Comment: I am not sure if it supports it or not, but when I was looking for something similar, I had not luck locating it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data supports this pattern through `@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef=...)`. To make it work with Spring Boot you could create your 2 `DataSources`, mark one of them `@Primary` and it will be used by the auto-configured `entityManagerFactory` bean. Then you add another and refer to them both individually in your 2 `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations.

I suppose you could even create a custom annotation for each of the two repository types and use it in `@EnableJpaRepositories(includeFilters=...)`, but if I were you I would get it working with a package scan first (i.e. just put the repositries for the 2 data source targets in different packages).